# Cannot Launch an Activity on touching anywhere in Main Activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-intent

Could please someone lend me a hand? I've been struggling with this problem for hours. I have a Main and Start activity, the Main is the Launcher with a bunch of information (TextViews), it should transit into Start activity as soon as someone touches the screen. I found some info on stack overflow on how to do this (setting the onTouchListener() on relative layout) however it does not work for me, so everytime I try with:

```
    RelativeLayout layout= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
    layout.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

it tells me to cast 'this' to 'OnTouchListener' and here's the outcome:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView display1;
TextView display2;
TextView display3;
TextView display4;
ImageView image1;
RelativeLayout layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_screen);
    getActionBar().setTitle("AutoSMS");
    RelativeLayout layout= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
    layout.setOnTouchListener((OnTouchListener) this);
    display1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    display2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    display3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    display4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    Intent openStarting = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    startActivity(openStarting);
    }

   }
```

Here's the Manifest, just in case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.autosms"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Start"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.START" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".End"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.END" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

The DDMS gives me ClassCastException, MainActivity cannot be cast to ViewOnTouchListener

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Your MainActivity must `implement OnTouchListener` and its methods. And do not cast anything without need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either implement your whole activity to be an `onTouchListener` or create a new `onTouchListener` when you add it. Like

> public class myActivity extends Activity implements onTouchListener

or

> thisObject.add(new onTouchListener(){
>
> > //TODO: Add code
>
> });

There is no need to cast your Activity as an onTouchListener when it isn't. Casting is when you get the certain value of something if it's possible like if you have a `double` and you want to get it's value as an `int`. You just need to make a new `onTouchListener` or turn your activity into one because you don't have any.